# Omiting parameters in pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following case class:

```
case class Cls(a: Int, b: Long, c: String, f: Int, d: Long, e: Long)
```

Now in pattern matching I want to just match the class, not all this parameters:

```
clsOpt match {
    case Some(Cls(a, b, c, f, d, e)) => println("matched")
}
```

Actually I dont care about params values. Is there a way to write it more concisely?

```
clsOpt match {
    case Some(Cls) => println("matched") // compile-error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this pattern

```
case Some(c: Cls) =>
```

As follows:

```
 scala> case class Cls(a: Int, b: Long, c: String, f: Int, d: Long, e: Long)
```

defined class Cls

```
scala> val x: Option[Cls] = Some(Cls(1, 2, "3", 4, 5, 6))
x: Option[Cls] = Some(Cls(1,2,3,4,5,6))

scala> x match { case Some(c: Cls) => println(s"matched: $c")  case None => }
matched: Cls(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: also worth noting that you can also ignore `c`. with `case Some(_: Cls) => println("matched")`

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the inner class like this:

```
clsOpt match {
  case Some(_) => println(clsOpt.get)
  case None => println("n")
}
```

Alternatively you could just ignore the values by using underscores:

```
clsOpt match {
  case Some(Cls(_,_,_,_,_,_)) => println("matched")
}
```

Comment: This is true but modifying `Cls` (adding/removing fields) might cause unnecessary compilation errors